# Problem with PHP_CodeSniffer and SVN pre-commit hook

Tags: php, svn, coding-style

I've recently downloaded the latest version of CodeSniffer (1.3.RC0). I prefer this version and not the stable one (1.2.2) because I want the "severity" feature.

I've modified an existing Drupal standard package to be compatible with this version of CodeSniffer and stablish my own severity policy. When I run the phpcs from command-line, I've no problems at all. It sniffs the code correctly, filters severity and works fine.

The problem comes when I try to automate the sniffs with the subversion pre-commit hook. It seems that the phpcs-svn-pre-commit script coming with this release is not working at all.

I've followed the guide in http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.svn-pre-commit.php step-by-step, but when I commit a file with coding standard errors (detected by command-line execution of phpcs and my Drupal standard package), subversion simply lets the file pass and commits the changes.

Has anybody been in the same problem?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED: execution examples.

```
$ phpcs --standard=Drupal --severity=4 ak_gourmet.module 
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/IcePHP.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/IcePHP.so: cannot open shared object file: No such     file or directory in Unknown on line 0
FILE: ...ce/trunk/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/custom/ak_gourmet/ak_gourmet.module
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 21 ERROR(S) AFFECTING 27 LINE(S)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  17 | ERROR   | Concat operator must be surrounded by spaces. Found "...
     |         | '<p>'. "; expected "... . "
  17 | ERROR   | Concat operator must be surrounded by spaces. Found "...
     |         | .'</p>';..."; expected "... .;..."
  40 | WARNING | A comma should follow the last multiline array item. Found:
     |         | MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
  53 | WARNING | A comma should follow the last multiline array item. Found:
...
```

Line added in subversion pre-commit hook (it is being executed):

```
# execute code sniffer with drupal standards
/usr/bin/scripts/phpcs-svn-pre-commit --standard=Drupal --severity=4 "$REPOS" -t "$TXN" >&2 || exit 1
```

Committing the incorrect file:

```
$ svn commit -m "Testing svn hook-precommit" ak_gourmet.module 
Enviando       ak_gourmet.module
Transmitiendo contenido de archivos .
Commit de la revisión 5814.
```

Comment: Solved, it needs an extra param to include Drupal extensions, so the correct usage in the hook pre-commit is:

    usr/bin/scripts/phpcs-svn-pre-commit --standard=Drupal --severity=4 --extensions=module,inc "$REPOS" -t "$TXN" >&2 || exit 1